# How to make Apache Camel delete a file at the end of a "direct" route?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a situation where I'm consuming from a `direct` endpoint.  The body of the `Exchange` contains a `File`.  Is there a way via the Spring DSL to delete this `File` at the end of the route?

For example, I have a route that looks like

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <to uri="file:/data/files"/>
</route>
```

The file gets copied to `/data/files`, but the original is left alone.

I know I can add something like

```
<to uri="bean:deleter?method=delete"/>
```

to the end of the route to perform the deletion, but I was wondering if there were a camel specific way to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that really depends on how you pick up the file. But seeing how in comments you seem to imply that the file is not coming from a `file` endpoint then I'm afraid that you're left with having to do the cleanup yourself.

If you are using `ProducerTemplate` to send the file to `direct` then you can delete it in the sender method:

```
try {
    ProducerTemplate template = ...;
    template.sendBody("direct:start", file);
} finally {
    file.delete();
}
```

Otherwise, you can either have a bean method that will do the deletion for you or - my suggestion - you could try to move the file reading behavior to Camel, so that your route with `file` instead of `direct`.

**EDIT:**

If you are using Camel 2.15+, you can also try using [`pollEnrich()` with dynamic URIs](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html#ContentEnricher-Usingdynamicuris.1), given that you previously set the file or filename name somewhere in the exchange (e.g. body, exchange property, header...):

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <pollEnrich>
        <!--Example for  java.io.File body-->
        <simple>file:${body.parent}?fileName=${body.name}&delete=true</simple>

        <!--Example for file dir and file name as exchange properties-->
        <!--<simple>file:${exchangeProperty.myFileDir}?fileName=${exchangeProperty.myFileName}&delete=true</simple>-->
    </pollEnrich>
    <to uri="file:/data/files"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't just move the file to a directory and have Camel pick it up from a file uri because there's other information in the Exchange that's needed for processing.  (I'm not just moving it to another directory like the simplified example shows.)  I'll look into using the ProducerTemplate.  That appears to be what I want.

Comment: @MilošMilivojević , doesn't pollEnrich enrich route with the file rather than write the file to the folder?

Comment: It does, but it also deletes the file afterwards, which is what the question was about :)

Comment: yeah but how would the file content end up on the direct consumer?

Comment: This **is** the direct consumer, you don't seem to understand what the example does.

Comment: That was not my question. From your example, it seems that even though nothing actually is put on the direct consumer, the poll enricher is still triggered if a file is put on the consuming folder? Is that case?

Comment: What you asked didn't really make sense to me so I really had no way of replying :) The route in question (consuming from `direct:start`) requires you to set two exchange properties - `myFileDir` and `myFileName` - which describe the file that needs to be processed. In this case, processing consists only of copying the said file to `/data/files`. As Keith said, the file is generated in another route that then calls the `direct:start` route. Poll enrich will read the generated file and delete it afterwards, which was what the man asked for.

Comment: Still not convinced based on the description in the question and comments by the OP but I'll stop the commenting since this is turning into a discussion.

Comment: Both the `ProducerTemplate` and `pollEnrich` methods solve my problem.  Thanks, @MilošMilivojević!

Comment: The pollEnrich solves a little different problem than I have. I'm in a situation where I receive a file via an http post, **first** write it 'to' a file, (to have it at least stored), process it further and need to 'remove' the file in the 'to' location. It can all be done, but I still wished the 'to' has an exceptionhandler where the it uses an 'error' folder. Something like:  `<to uri="file:/myApp/received?onError=.error" /> that is used if further on an error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, if you do **NOT** want to delete the file and treat it as read only

Set the **noop**

```
    from(direct:start) //
         .pollEnrich("file:/home/mypath?fileName=myfile.csv&noop=true&idempotent=false", 30000)
         .log("Read ${body}")
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to set the delete parameter to equal true in your original from endpoint when the file is picked up. For example:

```
from("file://inobox?delete=true")
```

For more parameters:
http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Comment: I'm consuming from a direct uri, not a file. The 'delete=true' doesn't apply here.

Comment: That depends. If the file originated from a `file`-endpoint, then the exchange is commited to that endpoint at the end of the route. No matter if you pass the exchange through `direct`- OR `seda`-endpoints on the way.

Comment: @Keith, not particulary obvious from your question when you say that the body of the exchange contains a file yet your consuming from a direct exchange. So how is the file being put on the direct consumer? Surely it must come from some other endpoint which picked up the file. You put the delete parameter there.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti You're right, it's not obvious.  Apologies.  It's not coming from a file endpoint, though.  The file is being generated by a bean's method in a different route, so there's nowhere to add the 'delete' paramater for this particular file.